# Gnome Update Manager stays at 100 % system load

Tags: debian, gnome, 64bit

I experience a strange behaviour on my Debian (Wheezy x64) every time I use the [Gnome Update Manager](http://packages.debian.org/de/sid/update-manager-gnome).

1. While downloading the files, the CPU load stays low. [image: CPU load low while downloading] ([click for better resolution](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/69/update1h.png/))
2. When the new packages are unpacked the CPU runs hot.[image: CPU load high while updating] ([click for better resolution](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/94/update2w.png/))
3. After finishing all updates the CPU load stays at 100 % (at least for one core) until I close the update manager.[image: CPU still high after updating] ([click for better resolution](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/545/update3b.png/))

While I can perfectly understand (1) and (2) I don't see why (3) is the case.

Can you explain?

[edit]
Before update:

```
  1  [||                                 3.3%]     Tasks: 80, 154 thr; 2 running
  2  [||                                 3.3%]     Load average: 0.15 0.21 0.18 
  Mem[|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||840/1907MB]     Uptime: 00:37:53
  Swp[                               0/2047MB]

  PID USER     PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 3054 marcel    20   0  327M 15028 10632 S  2.0  0.8  0:01.28 gnome-terminal
 1828 root      20   0  161M 22500  9980 R  1.0  1.2  0:43.00 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -verbose -audit
 3616 marcel    20   0 19820  1704  1176 R  1.0  0.1  0:01.49 htop
 2476 marcel    20   0 1035M  383M 34944 S  1.0 20.1  2:15.71 /usr/lib/iceweasel/firefox-bin
 2540 marcel    20   0 1035M  383M 34944 S  0.0 20.1  0:00.66 /usr/lib/iceweasel/firefox-bin
 2266 marcel    20   0  396M 56320 13212 S  0.0  2.9  0:14.18 mutter
 2282 marcel    20   0  522M 24896 16444 S  0.0  1.3  0:01.81 gnome-panel
 2306 marcel    20   0  434M 43896 20636 S  0.0  2.2  0:06.83 mono /usr/lib/docky/Docky.exe
 2255 marcel    20   0  382M 42124 11180 S  0.0  2.2  0:01.58 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-
 2450 marcel    20   0  804M  139M 32548 S  0.0  7.3  0:32.14 /usr/lib/icedove/icedove-bin
    1 root      20   0 10608   812   680 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.57 init [2]
  300 root      20   0 21756  1824   820 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.07 udevd --daemon
  431 root      20   0 21752  1244   336 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 udevd --daemon
  432 root      20   0 21752  1208   300 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 udevd --daemon
 1156 root      20   0 18924   964   708 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /sbin/rpcbind -w
 1171 statd     20   0 23104  1168   884 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /sbin/rpc.statd
 1191 root      20   0 31504   432   208 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/rpc.idmapd
 1378 root      20   0  115M  1644  1152 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.02 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
 1379 root      20   0  115M  1644  1152 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
 1380 root      20   0  115M  1644  1152 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
 1377 root      20   0  115M  1644  1152 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.04 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
 1403 root      20   0  3904    76     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/acpi_fakekeyd
 1408 messageb  20   0 24604  1936   800 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.40 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
 1438 root      20   0  147M  5208  4180 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
 2358 root      20   0  147M  5208  4180 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
 1418 root      20   0  147M  5208  4180 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.37 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
 1435 root      20   0 78444  3144  2532 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.02 /usr/sbin/modem-manager
 1445 root      20   0  126M  4064  2828 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.11 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd
 1440 root      20   0  126M  4064  2828 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.26 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd
 1467 daemon    20   0 16632   368   220 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/atd
 1500 root      20   0 22920  1924  1640 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
 1505 root      20   0  4208   816   504 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.11 /usr/sbin/acpid
 1526 avahi     20   0 34096  1696  1404 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.01 avahi-daemon: running [notebook-marce
 1527 avahi     20   0 33976   452   212 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
 1579 root      20   0 20364  1056   828 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/cron
 1590 root      20   0 29072  2940  2416 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.07 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /var/ru
 1825 root      20   0 72932  3112  2616 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/gdm3
 1804 root      20   0 72932  3112  2616 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.01 /usr/sbin/gdm3
 1813 Debian-e  20   0 48736  1012   568 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -q30m
F1Help  F2Setup F3SearchF4InvertF5Tree  F6SortByF7Nice -F8Nice +F9Kill  F10Quit
```

after update (with gnome-update-manager still running):

```
  1  [||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||100.0%]     Tasks: 87, 159 thr; 2 running
  2  [|||||                                                     7.2%]     Load average: 0.91 0.45 0.27 
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||947/1907MB]     Uptime: 00:40:25
  Swp[|                                                     0/2047MB]

  PID USER     PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
 3645 root      20   0  398M 57908 33632 S 100.  3.0  1:20.62 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/update-manager
 3658 root      20   0  398M 57908 33632 R 100.  3.0  1:18.40 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/update-manager
 1828 root      20   0  164M 23960 10556 S  1.0  1.2  0:47.46 /usr/bin/Xorg :0 -br -verbose -audit 0 -novtswitch -auth /var/run/gdm3/auth-for-De
 3054 marcel    20   0  327M 15028 10632 S  1.0  0.8  0:01.63 gnome-terminal
 3616 marcel    20   0 19936  1800  1176 R  0.0  0.1  0:03.67 htop
 2476 marcel    20   0 1103M  442M 34960 S  0.0 23.2  2:25.30 /usr/lib/iceweasel/firefox-bin
 2450 marcel    20   0  804M  139M 32548 S  0.0  7.3  0:32.28 /usr/lib/icedove/icedove-bin
 2266 marcel    20   0  398M 56888 13240 S  0.0  2.9  0:15.63 mutter
 3618 marcel    20   0 1103M  442M 34960 S  0.0 23.2  0:00.16 /usr/lib/iceweasel/firefox-bin
 2306 marcel    20   0  434M 44480 20924 S  0.0  2.3  0:07.73 mono /usr/lib/docky/Docky.exe
 2492 marcel    20   0 1103M  442M 34960 S  0.0 23.2  0:00.38 /usr/lib/iceweasel/firefox-bin
 2315 marcel    20   0  434M 44480 20924 S  0.0  2.3  0:00.30 mono /usr/lib/docky/Docky.exe
 2282 marcel    20   0  522M 25328 16444 S  0.0  1.3  0:02.00 gnome-panel
  300 root      20   0 21756  1828   820 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.11 udevd --daemon
 3660 root      20   0 57068  6596  2724 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.05 /usr/lib/libgconf2-4/gconfd-2
 2255 marcel    20   0  382M 42124 11180 S  0.0  2.2  0:01.75 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
 1445 root      20   0  126M  4064  2828 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.13 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd
 1440 root      20   0  126M  4064  2828 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.28 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd
 2181 marcel    20   0  151M  4408  3172 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.10 /usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login
 3628 marcel    20   0  162M  8064  6540 S  0.0  0.4  0:00.03 /usr/bin/gksu -k -D /usr/share/applications/update-manager.desktop -- /usr/bin/upd
 3620 marcel    20   0  210M 24800 11484 S  0.0  1.3  0:00.13 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/update-manager
 2487 marcel    20   0 1103M  442M 34960 S  0.0 23.2  0:01.34 /usr/lib/iceweasel/firefox-bin
 2540 marcel    20   0 1103M  442M 34960 S  0.0 23.2  0:00.66 /usr/lib/iceweasel/firefox-bin
    1 root      20   0 10608   812   680 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.57 init [2]
 1156 root      20   0 18924   964   708 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /sbin/rpcbind -w
 1171 statd     20   0 23104  1168   884 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /sbin/rpc.statd
 1191 root      20   0 31504   432   208 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/rpc.idmapd
 1378 root      20   0  115M  1644  1152 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.02 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
 1379 root      20   0  115M  1644  1152 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
 1380 root      20   0  115M  1644  1152 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
 1377 root      20   0  115M  1644  1152 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.04 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -c5
 1403 root      20   0  3904    76     0 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/acpi_fakekeyd
 1408 messageb  20   0 24604  1936   800 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.42 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system
 1438 root      20   0  147M  5208  4180 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
 2358 root      20   0  147M  5208  4180 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
 1418 root      20   0  147M  5208  4180 S  0.0  0.3  0:00.38 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager
 1435 root      20   0 78444  3144  2532 S  0.0  0.2  0:00.02 /usr/sbin/modem-manager
 1467 daemon    20   0 16632   368   220 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/atd
 1500 root      20   0 22920  1924  1640 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.00 /usr/sbin/bluetoothd
F1Help  F2Setup F3SearchF4InvertF5Tree  F6SortByF7Nice -F8Nice +F9Kill  F10Quit
```

Comment: Which program(s) is using the CPU? Run `htop` in a terminal (or your system monitor of choice).

Comment: thanks for your answer. At the moment there are no updates, therefore I cannot try. I will post the output right after the next update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the graphical frontend to your package manager is buggy. Unfortunately this happens relatively often with such GUIs. Other cause might have been that it was simply performing a CPU-intensive task - your third screenshot suggests that initramfs was being created, which can be the "culprit" in that particular update. If the same thing happens in the future, try to use a command-line tool instead and compare the results.

Comment: it happens at every update. It really seems like there is some kind of bug. However, I think somebody else would have noticed that - after all it's Debian...

Comment: Maybe, but maybe not. Definitely test with command-line tools. And don't assume "this cannot be me" - bugs *do* occur and there's always some first person that reports them. Keep in mind that most bugs show up only in very specific circumstances - you may belong to a tiny fraction of a percent of Debian users affected by that particular one.

Comment: ok, I will try apt-get upgrade tomorrow. If system load stays low I will file a bug report. Thank you